# "Ambiguous search mapping detected" thrown after adding Springfox 3.0.0 to SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox-boot-starter

I have a SpringBoot application (spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.0) and I want to use Swagger. I followed this [Baeldung-Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api), and I am unfortunately getting this exception on startup:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous search mapping detected.

This is due to the fact that I am in some cases overloading methods in my repositories as follows:

```
Page<Message> findByConversationId(Long conversationId, Pageable pageable);
List<Message> findByConversationId(Long conversationId);
```

The exception says that both methods

> are mapped to /findByConversationId! Tweak configuration to
> get to unambiguous paths!

Is there any way to overcome this issue ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer to your problem but it might help you.
Consider using **springdoc** instead of **Springfox**. It is a newer library that is easier to use and way less error-prone than Springfox. We moved to it 2 years ago and we are very glad we did. There is very good documentation and tutorials online for it:

- https://springdoc.org/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

It is also very active and you usually get your issues answered very fast on the [github page](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues).